# Sintaxe de acesso para dados membro de ponteiro para ponteiro de uma classe

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, ponteiro

Como funciona um ponteiro para ponteiro tratando-se de classes? Por exemplo:

```
class A{
public:
    int value;
};

int main(){
    A x;
    A* ptrx = &x;
    A** pptrx = &ptrx;

    //OK, retorna "value"
    std::cout << x.value << std::endl;

    //OK, o mesmo que "x.value"
    std::cout << ptrx->value << std::endl;

    //pptrx
    std::cout << /*pptrx?*/ << std::endl;
}
```

Como faço para retornar o valor de `x.value` usando o "apontador" `pptrx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O operador `ptrx->value` na verdade é o mesmo que `(*ptrx).value`, eu até vou colocar no código abaixo. Então para acessar um ponteiro deve dereferenciá-lo dessa forma, a seta é só uma facilidade, portanto usa a forma normal e depois pode até usar a seta normalmente para a outra [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int value;
};

int main(){
    A x;
    x.value = 1;
    A* ptrx = &x;
    A** pptrx = &ptrx;
    std::cout << x.value << std::endl;
    std::cout << ptrx->value << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*ptrx).value << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*pptrx)->value << std::endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZiN7QY). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/dkkfkzfy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/PointerPointer.cpp).

Answer (score 4):

> Como faço para retornar o valor de x.value usando o "apontador" pptrx?

Acho que já tem uma boa explicação acima. Mas vou repetir a seguir.

> Enquanto fazia alguns testes com ponteiros deparei-me com a seguinte
> questão: como funciona um ponteiro para ponteiro tratando-se de
> classes

Sobre o título em si é importante entender que **o fato de serem ponteiros para classe não faz a menor diferença**. É exatamente como em C, onde não faria diferença serem ponteiros para `struct`

#### Exemplo

```
    A*      pA = nullptr;
    A**     p2A = nullptr;
    A***    p3A = nullptr;
    A****   p4A = nullptr;
```

Nesse caso `p3A` é de que tipo? `p3A` é `A***`. Então

- *p3A é do tipo `A**`
- **p3A é do tipo `A*`
- e afinal ***p3A é do tipo `A`, uma instância da classe A.
- e é o que temos sempre: "tira o `*` de um lado e coloca do outro

Como está mesmo fazendo testes e esse eu acho que é um troço chato do C e do C++ vou deixar um exemplo com **mais** testes. A cada dia se usa menos e menos isso em C++, mas sempre vai ser um conceito essencial para linguagens para desenvolvimento de sistemas quando usadas para, por exemplo, desenvolvimento de sistemas :D

#### Sua classe `A` de teste, um pouco alterada

```
class A
{
public:
    int value;
    A() : A(42){};
    A(int v) : value(v){ cout << "Criada A com '" << value << "'\n";};
    ~A(){ std::cout << "Destruindo instancia de A(" << value << ")\n";};
};
```

Pra facilitar o exemplo acrescentei um construtor que aceita um `int` para por um valor direto, e criei um destrutor para ver quando a classe pode ser destruída no meio do programa, no caso de alocação dinâmica.

**Programas de teste são para isso afinal**

Vou postar uns trechos do programa e o trecho correspondente na saída, a seguir. Ao final vou deixar o programa todo e a saída toda.

#### trecho 1

```
    A x;        std::cout << x.value << std::endl;
    A y(300);   std::cout << y.value << std::endl;
    A* p1 = nullptr;
```

Esse trecho cria duas `A` com valores 42 (padrão) e 300 e gera

#### saída

```
Criada A com '42'
42
Criada A com '300'
300
```

#### trecho 2

```
    p1 = &x;
    std::cout << p1->value << std::endl;

    p1 = new A(322);
    std::cout << p1->value << std::endl;

    std::cout << "vai destruir p1\n";
    delete p1;
    std::cout << "continuando...\n";
```

faz `p1` apontar para `x` e mostra o valor. Mas a seguir aloca um novo `p1` apontando para uma nova `A` com valor 322. Em seguida apaga `p1` usando `delete` e então você vê o destrutor sendo chamado.

#### saida

```
42
Criada A com '322'
322
vai destruir p1
Destruindo instancia de A(322)
continuando...
```

#### Trecho 3

```
    A** pp1 = new A*(nullptr);
    pp1 = &p1;
    p1 = &y;
    cout << "pp1 aponta para p1 que aponta para y(300). Valor = " << (**pp1).value << "\n";
    delete pp1; // libera *pp1;
```

Agora declara `pp1` como `A**` e faz com que ele aponte para `p1`. `p1` não aponta para nada, foi alvo do `delete` np trecho 2. Mas então o programa faz `p1` apontar para y, e usa `**pp1` para imprimir o valor de `y` que é 300

#### Saida

```
pp1 aponta para p1 que aponta para y(300). Valor = 300
```

#### trecho 4

```
    *pp1 = &x; // reusa o ponteiro para apontar para o endereco de x
    (*pp1)->value = 18; // usa pp1 para alterar o valor de x
    cout << "Valor de x alterado para '" << x.value << "'\n";
    cout << "pp1 -> p1 -> x(18). Valor = " << (**pp1).value << "\n";
    cout << "ou de outro modo Valor = " << (*pp1)->value << "\n";
    cout << "ou ainda de outro modo Valor = " << (*(*pp1)).value << "\n";
```

`pp` foi alvo de um `delete` então não apontava para nada. Esse trecho aponta `pp1` para `x` e usa o ponteiro para mudar o valor de `x` para 18 e mostra algumas maneiras de acessar

#### saida

```
Valor de x alterado para '18'
pp1 -> p1 -> x(18). Valor = 18
ou de outro modo Valor = 18
ou ainda de outro modo Valor = 18
```

#### trecho final

```
    // um ultimo exemplo usando pp1 para apontar para x e y
    pp1 = (A**)::operator new( 2 *sizeof(A*) );
    pp1[0] = &y;
    pp1[1] = &x;
    cout << "\nx(" << x.value << ")\n";
    cout << "y(" << y.value << ")\n";
    cout << "Acessando os valores de x e y atraves do vetor\n\
de ponteiros para ponteiros para a classe A:\n\
Valores de y e x: (" <<
        pp1[0]->value << "," <<
        pp1[1]->value << 
        ")\n";
    delete pp1;
    cout << "\nFim\n";
```

Esse trecho tem a cara de um programa C, mas usa `pp1` que é `A**` para criar dois ponteiros e acessar os valores de `x` e `y`. Nada especial, considerando que é mais ou menos o que acontece com todo programa em C++ para criar a lista de parâmetros para `int main( int argc, char*[] argv)`.

Os ponteiros são alocados, passam a apontar para as instâncias `x` e `y` de `A` e são usados para mostrar os valores via `cout`. A seguir os ponteiros são liberados e o programa termina. Só então `x` e `y` são destruídas, o que fica claro na saída porque a mensagem "Fim" aparece antes dos destrutores de `x` e `y`

#### saída

```
x(18)
y(300)
Acessando os valores de x e y atraves do vetor
de ponteiros para ponteiros para a classe A:
Valores de y e x: (300,18)

Fim
Destruindo instancia de A(300)
Destruindo instancia de A(18)
```

#### O programa completo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    int value;
    A() : A(42){};
    A(int v) : value(v){ cout << "Criada A com '" << value << "'\n";};
    ~A(){ std::cout << "Destruindo instancia de A(" << value << ")\n";};
};

int main(void)
{
    A x;        std::cout << x.value << std::endl;
    A y(300);   std::cout << y.value << std::endl;
    A* p1 = nullptr;
    
    p1 = &x;
    std::cout << p1->value << std::endl;

    p1 = new A(322);
    std::cout << p1->value << std::endl;

    std::cout << "vai destruir p1\n";
    delete p1;
    std::cout << "continuando...\n";

    A** pp1 = new A*(nullptr);
    pp1 = &p1;
    p1 = &y;
    cout << "pp1 aponta para p1 que aponta para y(300). Valor = " << (**pp1).value << "\n";
    delete pp1; // libera *pp1;

    *pp1 = &x; // reusa o ponteiro para apontar para o endereco de x
    (*pp1)->value = 18; // usa pp1 para alterar o valor de x
    cout << "Valor de x alterado para '" << x.value << "'\n";
    cout << "pp1 -> p1 -> x(18). Valor = " << (**pp1).value << "\n";
    cout << "ou de outro modo Valor = " << (*pp1)->value << "\n";
    cout << "ou ainda de outro modo Valor = " << (*(*pp1)).value << "\n";

    // um ultimo exemplo usando pp1 para apontar para x e y
    pp1 = (A**)::operator new( 2 *sizeof(A*) );
    pp1[0] = &y;
    pp1[1] = &x;
    cout << "\nx(" << x.value << ")\n";
    cout << "y(" << y.value << ")\n";
    cout << "Acessando os valores de x e y atraves do vetor\n\
de ponteiros para ponteiros para a classe A:\n\
Valores de y e x: (" <<
        pp1[0]->value << "," <<
        pp1[1]->value << 
        ")\n";
    delete pp1;
    cout << "\nFim\n";
    return 0;
}
```

#### a saída completa

```
PS C:\src\CPP> g++ -o tst -Wall -std=c++2a tst.cpp
PS C:\src\CPP> ./tst
Criada A com '42'
42
Criada A com '300'
300
42
Criada A com '322'
322
vai destruir p1
Destruindo instancia de A(322)
continuando...
pp1 aponta para p1 que aponta para y(300). Valor = 300
Valor de x alterado para '18'
pp1 -> p1 -> x(18). Valor = 18
ou de outro modo Valor = 18
ou ainda de outro modo Valor = 18

x(18)
y(300)
Acessando os valores de x e y atraves do vetor
de ponteiros para ponteiros para a classe A:
Valores de y e x: (300,18)

Fim
Destruindo instancia de A(300)
Destruindo instancia de A(18)
PS C:\src\CPP>
```